# Null pointer exception with static hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, nullpointerexception

```
 public class arraylst
 {
   static HashMap<String,List<String>>hm;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       hm.put("2",Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
   }
 }
```

I don't understand why this causes `NullPointerException`.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Because `hm` is null -- you *never* assign an object to it. Now, let's please close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `hm`:

```
hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `HashMap<String,List<String>>` into your (initially empty) `hm` field.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
static HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike primitive variables, the Classes should be explicitly initialized. So create an instance of HasMap.

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to a reference which don't have a Object. So you are trying to refer a Object which haven't yet created.

So using the "new" key word create an Object to overcome the exception

```
static HashMap<String,List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```